# linux bash to sort text file by 'yymmdd' instead of 'ddmmyy' column format, then sort by time, then remove duplicates

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Greeting.
I Please need to sort lines, in a text file that has 11 fields separated by comma.

- column 10 contain date in the format **'ddmmyy'**
- column 1 contain timestamp in the format **'hhmmss.sss'**

-sorting criteria 1, to sort by column 10, but first by year, then by month, then by day,
like if date format was **'yymmdd'** instead of **'ddmmyy'**

-sorting criteria 2, to sort by column 2, containing timestamp.

this is an example file

```
$GPSACP: 100054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,280521,05
$GPSACP: 140054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,160621,05
$GPSACP: 210038.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160621,03
$GPSACP: 210038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160615,03
$GPSACP: 100038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280717,03
$GPSACP: 100038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280518,03
$GPSACP: 210039.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
$GPSACP: 211054.764,1057.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,280521,05
$GPSACP: 211054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,160621,05
$GPSACP: 210538.264,1026.4148N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160614,03
$GPSACP: 210538.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160621,03
$GPSACP: 211638.265,1026.5147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
$GPSACP: 211539.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
```

this is what i wish to have as a result :

```
$GPSACP: 210538.264,1026.4148N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160614,03

$GPSACP: 210038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160615,03

$GPSACP: 100038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280717,03

$GPSACP: 100038.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280518,03

$GPSACP: 100054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,280521,05
$GPSACP: 211638.265,1026.5147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
$GPSACP: 211539.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
$GPSACP: 210039.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,280521,03
$GPSACP: 211054.764,1057.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,280521,05
$GPSACP: 140054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,160621,05
$GPSACP: 210038.264,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160621,03
$GPSACP: 210538.265,1026.4147N,00129.9725E,3.75,87.0,3,43.87,2.58,1.39,160621,03
$GPSACP: 211054.764,1056.0063N,00002.9733E,1.75,91.0,3,236.46,0.40,0.22,160621,05
```

I would like to use bash sort but i don't know in particular how to treat date in different order.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks. Mario.

Comment: does each line of your file start with the literal string `$GPSACP: ` ??? if not, please update the question to show **just** the contents of the file; you mention wanting to use `sort` ... please update the question with what you've tried so far

Comment: Your sample output appears to have lines 6 and 7 in the wrong place.  (Presumably the blank lines are not supposed to be present?)

Comment: $GPSACP: prefix it is constant. Blank lines are NOT suppose to be present.

Comment: If blank lines aren't supposed to be present then [edit] your question to remove them.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming either every line starts with `$GPSACP:`  or none of them do, you can use `sort`:

```
sort -t, -k10.5,10.6 -k10.3,10.4 -k10.1,10.2 -k1,1 input.txt
```

This effectively splits column 10 into three 2-digit chunks, which can then be sorted independently. Then it is subsorted by column 1. (Because the column 1 prefix is constant it doesn't affect the ordering.) The `-t` option changes the column delimiter to be comma.

---

If the `$GPSACP:`  prefix is **not** constant, if you have a version of `sort` that supports the "stable sort" option (`-s`), then you can presort by (space-delimited) column 2, then sort by the parts of column 10:

```
sort -k2 input.txt | sort -t, -k10.5,10.6 -k10.3,10.4 -k10.1,10.2 -s
```

Comment: Dear jhnc, $GPSACP: prefix it is constant. Your first answer is what i was looking for. 
Thank You. Thank You for the explanation to make me understand the code. 
Much Appreciated.